# How do i get the full root file path of the current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I need to get the full file path of the current workbook to ensure the file hasn't been moved to another location/saved on the users desktop so I will use this on the workbook open event to work out if it has been opened from the shared drive or from a users desktop.

I have tried this:

```
Dim WBpath As String

Wbpath = Application.ThisWorkbook.path

Debug.Print Wbpath
```

which gives me the file path but its showing the mapped shared drive letter and not the actual full drive path E.G:

`W:\SHARED FOLDER\Form`

However as different users will have mapped the drive under different letters I need the full path eg:

`\\server.company.abc\H67362\SHARED FOLDER\FORM`

I tried this on a few files and some come back with the full path. and others come back with the mapped drive letter so i have no idea why or how to get around this.

Can someone assist please?
thanks in advance.